# Obtener segundo valor de una lista en python

Tags: python, json, odoo, openerp

estoy teniendo ciertos problemas al hacer una consulta y traducir algunos de los terminos que trae consigo la consulta.
Tengo un JSON que envía ciertos datos a Circulo de Crédito & regresa un JSON, hasta ahí todo bien, el problema es que en algunos campos viene el código o identificador del término en lugar de su traducción.

A continuación les muestro el catálogo (lo recorto un poco porque es bastante extenso):

```
catalogo_razones = {
        'A0' : 'Historial de pago de la cuenta es demasiado nuevo',
        'A1' : 'Último reporte de la Cuenta en estatus de morosidad',
        'A2' : 'Monto de crédito disponibles en cuentas revolventes',
        'A3' : 'Monto de deuda en cuentas es demasiado alto',
        'A4' : 'Monto de deuda en el banco/nacional en cuentas revolventes',
        'A5' : 'Monto de deuda clasificado en cobranza',
        'A6' : 'Monto de deuda en las cuentas morosas',
        'A7' : 'Monto de deuda en cuentas abiertas recientemente es demasiado alto',
        'A8' : 'Monto de deuda en cuentas revolventes abiertas recientemente de banco/nacionales es muy alta',
        'A9' : 'Monto de deuda en cuentas abiertos recientemente en empresas de financiamiento al consumo es demasiado alto',
        'B0' : 'Monto de deuda en cuentas de minoristas abiertas recientemente es demasiado alta',
        'B1' : 'Monto de deuda en cuentas revolventes abiertas recientemente es demasiado alto',
        'B2' : 'Monto de deuda en cuentas de empresas de financiamiento de ventas abiertas recientemente es muy alto'
}
```

al hacer la consulta todo bien, hace la traducción sin problema, el verdadero problema es que en lugar de guardar la traducción de la razón, guarda el código id.

Básicamente lo que quiero es que guarde el contenido de la columna **valor**.

A continuación les proporciono el código donde se llama al catálogo de razones y la captura de pantalla del depurador

```
#Score
score = response.get("scores")
zero = (score[0])
razon = (zero['razones'])
rt = api.traducir_razones(razon)

for each in rt:
    
    datosScore = {'partner_id': self.id,
                  'nombre_score': zero.get('nombreScore'),
                  'valor_score': zero.get('valor'),
                  'razon': each,
                 }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna **valor** solo es el resultado de un punto de interrupción en la variable **rt**

Les dejo a continuación el punto de interrupción

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: donde esta la columna **valor**.?

Comment: es una columna parte del debug, solo aparece cuando se analiza la variable **rt** con un punto de interrupción

Comment: Hola, Anibal. Seria bueno que especificarás mejor lo que quieres hacer, al menos en mi caso, no logre entender lo que quieres. Nota: la columna valor no existe y tampoco tiene contenido porque ella es parte de la GUI cuando inspeccionas el código. Lo que realmente tiene contenido es el diccionario rt ¿que deseas hacer con ese contenido?

Comment: El contenido de RT es la traducción, lo que quiero es que lo que está en la columna valor (que vendría siendo la traducción) se guarde en **each**